# Сочетание точки и тире

Tags: пунктуация

В каким случаях ставится точка и тире **. —**? Например,

"Все удивительное здесь надо отнести на счет игры антитезы; разум здесь ничего не выигрывает **. —** Но там, где дело касается спорных для разума вопросов..." ;

"...это бытие, совершая поступательное движение, уходя от себя самого, становится в то же время моментом мышления **. —** Если, согласно данному возражению..." ;

"Для нашей цели достаточно этого изображения земной жизни в ее целом и во всех ее отдельных эпохах **. —** Как несомненно то, что современная нам эпоха есть часть земной жизни...".

Answer (score 1):

По внешним признакам, здесь авторский комментарий (в форме полемики с автором цитируемого текста) расположен внутри цитируемого абзаца. В аналогичных случаях разрыва прямой речи кавычки остаются в начале и в конце, однако точку (в отличие от других знаков в конце предложения) принято заменять запятой и связывать законченную часть реплики или цитаты с началом авторского текста через тире. Здесь, видимо, в интересах сохранения пунктуации цитируемого текста, ограничились выделением комментария при помощи тире, что и привело к такому сочетанию знаков.  Оно встречается и в некоторых случаях оформления прямой речи, но не в таких - возможно, существуют какие-то специализированные редакционные рекомендации относительно комментариев в тексте. Из ваших незаконченных примеров неясно, есть ли после авторских вставок, напр. указание в скобках, что это комментарий, или какие-либо общие оговорки условностей перед самим текстом, позволяющие относить соотв. вставки к комментарию.

Comment: Нет-нет... Кавычками я здесь не хотел показать прямую речь. Я просто выделил эти примеры из повествовательных текстов и решил как пример выделить кавычками.
Я точно не могу ответить на Ваш последний вопрос, поэтому предлагаю сделать Вам вывод самостоятельно, просто вставив примеры в адресную строку и найдя тексты, откуда я их выделил. Ни авторских вставок, ни комментариев я не встретил.

Comment: Очень похоже на особенности программного распознавания текста: в некоторых сетевых источниках знак параграфа распознался как "=". Возможно, на местах длинных тире в оригинале был какой-то вовсе нестандартный или декоративный символ. Такие места там встречаются очень часто. В отсканированном виде попадается этот текст?

Comment: да, есть. Посмотрел во всех источниках, в том числе и у других авторов.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, это **авторский знак**, обозначающий нечто среднее между двумя отдельными предложениями и сложным предложением.  Можно представить, что  **точка и тире** -  своеобразный аналог точки с запятой (на месте обычной  запятой) с ее тематикой: значительная распространённость, собственные знаки препинания, отдалённость темы, смысловое разграничение, но при этом точка и тире **соответствует  подчеркнутой паузе**.

Можно предположить, что это **обозначение парцелляции** (она же пока никак не обозначается).

Что касается правил, то мне такие не встречались. Возможно, это новое явление, которое правилами еще не охвачено.

Answer (score 0):

> В каким случаях ставится точка и тире . —? Например...

Как я понял, все три приведённых в вопросе примера взяты из философских произведений, написанных в XIX  веке и в настоящее время переизданных  — переизданных, скорее всего, с сохранением (или с частичным сохранением) пунктуации, имевшей место при их написании.

Как пишет **Валгина** *("Актуальные проблемы современной русской пунктуации", М., 2004)*,

> …примерно до середины XIX века в качестве конечного знака часто
>   употреблялось **сочетание точки и тире**.  Ср., например, у А.
>   Пушкина:
>
> *Под сенью хаты скромной,*
>
> *В часы печали томной,*
>
> *Была ты предо мной*
>
> *С лампадой и мечтой. —*
>
> (К моей чернильнице.)
>
> .
>
> Не избежал этого и Ф.И. Тютчев…
>
> Особенно показательно, что точка и тире как единый знак конца
>   предложения употребляется Ф.И. Тютчевым в письмах самого
>   разнообразного содержания — и бытового, и официально-делового.
>   **Значит, это знак не особый, поэтического звучания, а обычного для первой половины   XIX века употребления, знак, соответствующий
>   принятым нормам.**